# Using map() on a function with multiple inputs to get rid of for loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, list-comprehension

**Context:**

I have a function to upsample multiple arrays that I want to write as efficiently as possible (because I have to run it 370000 times).

This function takes multiple inputs and is composed of 2 `for` loops. To upsample my arrays, I loop over this function with a parameter `k`, and I would like to get rid of this loop (which sits outside of the function). I tried using a mix of `map()` and *list-comprehension* to minimize my computing time but I can't make it work.

**Question:**

How to get my `map()` part of the code working (*see last section of code*) ? Is there a better way than `map()` to get rid of `for` loops ?

**Summary:**

- Function `interpolate_and_get_results`: 2 `for` loops. Takes 3D, 2D arrays and `int` as inputs
- This function is ran inside a `for` loop (parameter `k`) that I want to get rid of

I wrote some example code, the part with `map()` does not work because I can't think of a way to pass the `k` parameter as a *list*, but also an *input*.

Thank you !

ps: [code to parallelize the interpolation function that I do not use for this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399050/parallelize-three-nested-loops/72399494?noredirect=1#comment127919686_72399494)

```
import numpy as np
import time

#%% --- SETUP OF THE PROBLEM --- %%#

temperatures = np.random.rand(10,4,7)*100
precipitation = np.random.rand(10,4,7)
snow = np.random.rand(10,4,7)

# Flatten the arrays to make them iterable with map()
temperatures = temperatures.reshape(10,4*7)
precipitation = precipitation.reshape(10,4*7)
snow = snow.reshape(10,4*7)

# Array of altitudes to "adjust" the temperatures
alt = np.random.rand(4,7)*1000

# Flatten the array
alt = alt.reshape(4*7)

# Weight Matrix

w = np.random.rand(4*7, 1000, 1000)


#%% Function
def interpolate_and_get_results(temp, prec, Eprec, w, i, k):
    
    # Do some calculations
    factor1 = ((temperatures[i,k]-272.15) + (-alt[k] * -6/1000))
    factor2 = precipitation[i,k]
    factor3 = snow[i,k]
    
    # Iterate through every cell of the upsampled arrays
    for i in range(w.shape[1]):
        for j in range(w.shape[2]):
            val = w[k, i, j]
            temp[i, j] += factor1 * val
            prec[i, j] += factor2 * val
            Eprec[i, j] += factor3 * val


    

#%% --- Function call without loop simplification --- ##%
# Prepare a template array
dummy = np.zeros((w.shape[1], w.shape[2]))

# Initialize the global arrays to be filled
tempYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
precYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
EprecYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))

ts = time.time()
for i in range(temperatures.shape[0]):
    
    # Create empty host arrays
    temp = dummy.copy()
    prec = dummy.copy()
    Eprec = dummy.copy()
    
    for k in range(w.shape[0]):
         interpolate_and_get_results(temp, prec, Eprec, w, i, k)

print('Time: ', (time.time()-ts))




#%% --- With Map (DOES NOT WORK)  --- %%#
del k

dummy = np.zeros((w.shape[1], w.shape[2]))

# Initialize the global arrays to be filled
tempYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
precYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
EprecYEAR2 = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))

# Create a list k to be iterated through with the map() function
k = [k for k in range(0, temperatures.shape[1])]

for i in range(temperatures.shape[0]):
    
    # Create empty host arrays
    temp = dummy.copy()
    prec = dummy.copy()
    Eprec = dummy.copy()
    
    # Call the interpolate function with map() iterating through k
    map(interpolate_and_get_results(temp, prec, Eprec, w, i, k), k)
```

Code from @Jérôme Richard using `numba` added at the request of user @ken (takes 48.81s to run on my pc):

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time



#%% ------ Create data ------ ###
temperatures = np.random.rand(10,4,7)*100
precipitation = np.random.rand(10,4,7)
snow = np.random.rand(10,4,7)

# Array of altitudes to "adjust" the temperatures
alt = np.random.rand(4,7)*1000


#%% ------ IDW Interpolation ------ ###

# We create a weight matrix that we use to upsample our temperatures, precipitations and snow matrices
# This part is not that important, it works well as it is

MX,MY = np.shape(temperatures[0])
N = 300

T = np.zeros([N*MX+1, N*MY+1])

# create NxM inverse distance weight matrices based on Gaussian interpolation

x = np.arange(0,N*MX+1)
y = np.arange(0,N*MY+1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

k = 0
w =  np.zeros([MX*MY,N*MX+1,N*MY+1])
for mx in range(MX):
    for my in range(MY):

        # Gaussian
        add_point = np.exp(-((mx*N-X.T)**2+(my*N-Y.T)**2)/N**2)
        w[k,:,:] += add_point
        k += 1

sum_weights = np.sum(w, axis=0)
for k in range(MX*MY):
    w[k,:,:] /= sum_weights






#%% --- Function --- %%#
# Code from Jérôme Richard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399050/parallelize-three-nested-loops/72399494?noredirect=1#comment127919686_72399494

import numba as nb

# get_results + interpolator
@nb.njit('void(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], int_, int_, int_, int_)', parallel=True)
def interpolate_and_get_results(temp, prec, Eprec, w, i, k, mx, my):
    factor1 = ((temperatures[i,mx,my]-272.15) + (-alt[mx, my] * -6/1000))
    factor2 = precipitation[i,mx,my]
    factor3 = snow[i,mx,my]

    # Filling the
    for i in nb.prange(w.shape[1]):
        for j in range(w.shape[2]):
            val = w[k, i, j]
            temp[i, j] += factor1 * val
            prec[i, j] += factor2 * val
            Eprec[i, j] += factor3 * val




#%% --- Main Loop --- %%#



ts = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    dummy = np.zeros((w.shape[1], w.shape[2]))

    # Initialize the permanent arrays to be filled
    tempYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    precYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    EprecYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    smbYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    
    # Initialize semi-permanent array
    smb = np.zeros((dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))



    # Loop over the "time" axis
    for i in range(0, temperatures.shape[0]):

        # Create empty semi-permanent arrays
        temp = dummy.copy()
        prec = dummy.copy()
        Eprec = dummy.copy()

        # Loop over the different weights
        for k in range(w.shape[0]):

            # Loops over the cells of the array to be upsampled
            for mx in range(MX):
                for my in range(MY):

                    interpolate_and_get_results(temp, prec, Eprec, w, i, k, mx, my)

        # At each timestep, update the semi-permanent array using the results from the interpolate function
        smb[np.logical_and(temp <= 0, prec > 0)] += prec[np.logical_and(temp <= 0, prec > 0)]

        # Fill the permanent arrays (equivalent of storing the results at the end of every year)
        # and reinitialize the semi-permanent array every 5th timestep
        if i%5 == 0:
            
            # Permanent
            tempYEAR[int(i/5)] = temp
            precYEAR[int(i/5)] = prec
            EprecYEAR[int(i/5)] = Eprec
            smbYEAR[int(i/5)] = smb

            # Semi-permanent
            smb = np.zeros((dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))


print("Time spent:", time.time()-ts)
```

Comment: First, just because the code doesn't have `for` in it doesn't mean it isn't still doing a `for` loop. So, switching to map likely won't help anything because the work still has to be done.
For a solution, look at [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: This is quite an advanced topic you scratch here. It's connected to theoretical computer science, complexity and the Big-O notation. Those keywords might be a starting point for further research.

Apart of that, I think this question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything. But I see you update cells of global objects. Curious, does this work? Can you explain in words what your are attempting to do with these arrays and desired result?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, these are great resources I will check out.

Comment: @Parfait Yes it updates my arrays even without a `return` command. In short: I have a coarse hourly dataset (temperatures etc...) over 40 years that I upsample in space at each timestep: every hour. Every hour still, I update a semi-permanent array with the temporary arrays I calculate within my function. At the end of each year, I then store this semi-permanent array in a permanent array and reinitialize it. Then, I repeat the process for 40 years.

Comment: Note that `interpolate_and_get_results` was very fast with Numba because it can compile the code to a native binary. However, it is very slow without since the interpreter make horribly inefficient things when you naively use for example `temp[i, j]`. The gap is likely to be a 100 to 10000 speed-up. You should not remove the `@nb.njit` of the previous answer if you care about performance.

Comment: Thank you @JérômeRichard ! I did not put your function with numba because I thought it would be less confusing to put the `simpler` function as a code example. I tried to speed up the process around your function but I don't think I have the skills to code that yet. Thank you for taking time to follow up on that !

Comment: `map` and list comprehension can streamline certain `for` loops, but they don't significantly change the speed.  Nothing like using compiled numpy methods or `numba` code, both of which put the loops in compiled code.

Comment: In python3, map just creates an iterator. You need to iterate on your own to actually process it. I'm pretty sure that just using map won't improve anything at all. In fact, it will probably slower. By the way, your "simpler" function can be easily sped up with numpy broadcasts, have you optimized that part already? It would be easier to find a better way if you could show us the actual code.

Comment: @ken the fastest code I have so far is the one optimized by @Jérôme Richard who rewrote my function and uses `numba`. He hinted that there might be a way to get rid of the loops or speedup the process even more, which is why I created this question after trying unsuccessfully. I added the full code to the question at your request. Thank you !

Comment: `map` and list comprehensions will not make your code faster. It will essentially just be a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note: This answer is not about how to use map, it's about "a better way".

You are doing a lot of redundant calculations. Believe it or not, this code outputs the same result.

```py
# No change in the initialization section above.

ts = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    dummy = np.zeros((w.shape[1], w.shape[2]))

    # Initialize the permanent arrays to be filled
    tempYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    precYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    EprecYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))
    smbYEAR = np.zeros((9, dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))

    smb = np.zeros((dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))

    temperatures_inter = temperatures - 272.15
    w_inter = w.sum(axis=0)
    alt_inter = (alt * (-6 / 1000)).sum()

    for i in range(0, temperatures_inter.shape[0]):
        temp_i = (temperatures_inter[i].sum() - alt_inter) * w_inter
        prec_i = precipitation[i].sum() * w_inter
        Eprec_i = snow[i].sum() * w_inter

        condition = np.logical_and(temp_i <= 0, prec_i > 0)
        smb[condition] += prec_i[condition]

        if i % 5 == 0:
            tempYEAR[i // 5] = temp_i
            precYEAR[i // 5] = prec_i
            EprecYEAR[i // 5] = Eprec_i
            smbYEAR[i // 5] = smb
            smb = np.zeros((dummy.shape[0], dummy.shape[1]))

print("Time spent:", time.time() - ts)
```

I verified the results by comparing them to the output of the code that uses numba. The difference is about 0.0000001, which is probably caused by rounding error.

```py
print((tempYEAR_from_yours - tempYEAR_from_mine).sum())  # -8.429287845501676e-08
print((precYEAR_from_yours - precYEAR_from_mine).sum())  # 2.595697878859937e-09
print((EprecYEAR_from_yours - EprecYEAR_from_mine).sum())  # -7.430216442116944e-09
print((smbYEAR_from_yours - smbYEAR_from_mine).sum())  # -6.875431779462815e-09
```

On my PC, this code took 0.36 seconds. It does not use numba and is not even parallelized. It just eliminated redundancy.

Comment: Thank you ! However I made a mistake: I forgot to specify that I need to calculate the arrays for each timestep. I modified the code with Numba (added 2 arrays: `smbYEAR` and `smb`). My real code is much longer and is not suited for stack. But there are multiple other arrays like `smb` that I update at each timestep, store in a permanent array once a year (`smbYEAR`), then reinitialize once a year (or every 5th iteration like in the code above).

Comment: Yup, I thought something was wrong because you only saved them once every 5 iterations. However, for `smbYEAR` and `smp` you added, I don't have to change my code much. See my update. My point is that eliminating redundant calculations is most important and effective, and you should consider it first. If it is not suited for SO, then perhaps it is better to try somewhere else. (As @Finomnis mentioned in his comment, maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?)

Comment: Thank you @ken ! It's my first step into optimization and the way you got rid of the iterations is helping a lot. I'll try to implement that in my code now. I'll also probably post something on the code review if I feel it can be improved. Thanks again !